# retrieve values by the column names in python psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> tb = 'races';
>>> conn2 = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost',dbname=latest_prod_copy,port=5438)
>>> cursor2.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT * from {}").format(sql.Identifier(tb)))
>>> cursor2.description[0]
Column(name='id', type_code=23, display_size=None, internal_size=4, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None)
>>> cursor2.description[0][0]
'id'
>>> cursor2.description[0][1]
23
```

My question is how to retrieve values by the key? such as cursor2.description[0]->'type_code', instead of cursor2.description[0][1]

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Column
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description

Answer (score 2):

`cursor2.description[0]` is a `psycopg2.extensions.Column` object, you can access its fields by name, e.g.

```
cursor2.description[0].type_code
```

Comment: You beat me by 1 minute.